# Twitter API returns Error 401 (using OAuthSwift)

Tags: swift, oauth, alamofire, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to access Twitter API and getting Error 401. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? OAuth URL Callback is successful and I get aouth_token and oauth_secret as well. But when I try to access the API, I'm getting 401 in Postman. Thank you in advance.

```
1. consumer_key
2. consumer_secret
3. oauth_token
4. oauth_token_secret
```

Attaching postman screenshot. 
[Twitter API 401 Error in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5L7I.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing some of the required codes. Do you have `access_token` and
`access_token_secret`? I have 4 access codes in total, it looks to me like you only got 2.

Error `400` means that the request was invalid or cannot be otherwise served. Requests without authentication are considered invalid and will yield this response. Is there an accompanying error message explaining the error?

Check your app settings to see if you have those other codes! Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question. I indeed have 4 access codes in total. I'm getting 401 even with 4 access codes. I'm trying it from Postman now. If I can get it right in Postman, I will write in Swift myself.